# Changing a materialized view column's length after a change in the base table?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

We changed the underlying table column size (length). So the materialized view which is built on that table throws an error now since the MV column still has the old size.

This is an Oracle 11gR2 database.

How can I change the MV column's length to match the table's new column size without dropping the MV and recreating it?

Comment: Did you tried to compile the materialized view? `alter materialized view <your_mv_here> compile`

Comment: i tried, the column size/length is still the same, not changed to the table's column new size/length...

Answer (score 3):

You have to drop and recreate.

If you look at the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_2001.htm), you can see that only modification of the storage clauses are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not shown in the Oracle documentation, but you can simply use *alter* clause to change the column length in mview:

```
alter materialized view xxx modify (col varchar2(new_size));
```